# count function not working in switch

Tags: php, switch-statement

My problem here is that the count function won't work inside this switch statement, and I'm not sure why. I know there's probably a better way to do this, but I'm just trying to figure this out specifically to get it to work.

```
switch(count($matches[1]))
{
case count($matches[1]) = 1:
print "$matches[1][0] <input type=\"text\" name=\"$matches[1][0]\" /><br />";
break;

case count($matches[1]) = 2:
print "$matches[1][0] <input type=\"text\" name=\"$matches[1][0]\" /><br />
$matches[1][1] <input type=\"text\" name=\"$matches[1][1]\" /><br />";
break;

case count($matches[1]) = 3:
print "$matches[1][0] <input type=\"text\" name=\"$matches[1][0]\" /><br />
$matches[1][1] <input type=\"text\" name=\"$matches[1][1]\" /><br />
$matches[1][2] <input type=\"text\" name=\"$matches[1][2]\" /><br />";
break;

default:
print "Error";
}
```

I know that the count function and $matches work. 
Here are the two pages I have right now for reference.
First page:

```
<form action="emailform.php" method="post">
<textarea rows="20" cols="20" name="template[]"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Store your template here" />
</form>

<p>This is where you enter your standard email.<br />
The words that need to change every time are variables using the parenthesis {{}} i.e.
{{Customer name}}, {{item}}, {{price}}</p>
```

Second page:

```
<?php

$pattern = "/\{{2}([a-zA-Z]*)\}{2}/";

$subject = $_POST["template"];

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);


echo "<pre>";
var_dump($matches);
echo "</pre>";

echo count($matches[1]);

?>
<form action="emailform.php" method="post">
<?php
switch(count($matches[1]))
{
case count($matches[1]) = 1:
print "$matches[1][0] <input type=\"text\" name=\"$matches[1][0]\" /><br />";
break;

case count($matches[1]) = 2:
print "$matches[1][0] <input type=\"text\" name=\"$matches[1][0]\" /><br />
$matches[1][1] <input type=\"text\" name=\"$matches[1][1]\" /><br />";
break;

case count($matches[1]) = 3:
print "$matches[1][0] <input type=\"text\" name=\"$matches[1][0]\" /><br />
$matches[1][1] <input type=\"text\" name=\"$matches[1][1]\" /><br />
$matches[1][2] <input type=\"text\" name=\"$matches[1][2]\" /><br />";
break;

case count($matches[1]) = 4:
print "$matches[1][0] <input type=\"text\" name=\"$matches[1][0]\" /><br />
$matches[1][1] <input type=\"text\" name=\"$matches[1][1]\" /><br />
$matches[1][2] <input type=\"text\" name=\"$matches[1][2]\" /><br />
$matches[1][3] <input type=\"text\" name=\"$matches[1][3]\" />";
break;

default:
print "Error";
}

?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, You have used `case count($matches[1])` in all `case`

```
switch(count($matches[1]))
{
 case  1:
...
```

instead of

```
switch(count($matches[1]))
{
case count($matches[1]) = 1:
```

**Updates:**

HTML:

```
<form action="emailform.php" method="post">
    <textarea rows="20" cols="20" name="template">Dear {{customer}}, Your {{item}} will cost price. Thank you.</textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Store your template here" />
</form>
```

PHP in emailform.php

```
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $pattern = "/\{{2}([a-zA-Z]*)\}{2}/";   

    echo $subject = $_POST["template"];     
    preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);       

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($matches);
    echo "</pre>";

    foreach($matches[1] as $key=>$value){           
        print $value ."<input type=\"text\" name=\"$value\" /><br />";          
    }   
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I now have "notice:array to string conversion" and the switch has returned "Array[0] and Array[1]". But outside of the switch $matches[1][0] returns the items correctly.

Comment: What is the `var_dump($matches)` values?

Comment: `array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "{{customer}}"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "{{item}}"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "customer"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "item"
  }
}`

Comment: What is the `$_POST["template"]` value ?

Comment: `Dear {{customer}}, Your {{item}} will cost price. Thank you.`

Comment: Do you have only one textarea or multiple ? i.e the reason for `template[]` using in your html

Comment: I have re-written your code, use my answer update section  instead of your switch and all.